# convert decimal to string - mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

So I have noticed that some of my location data has been stored as decimal which is fine - but now I need to show them as a string.

I am wondering how can I convert the decimal to string.

```
location.find({},'location').limit(5000).exec(function(err,result) {
        if(err){
            res.send(err)
        }
        console.log(result)
       // string = "eqfeed_callback('features':["+result+"])";
        res.json(result);
        
    });
```

I know I need to use `{ $convert: { input: <expression>, to: "string" } }`

But where?

I have tried:

```
$addFields:{
  loc: { $toString: "$location.coordinates[0]" }
}
```

But no success.

I tried the below answer and got

```
const location = require('mongoose').model('listenerslocation');
    location.find({},
        {
          location: {
            coordinates: {
              $map: {
                input: "$location.coordinates",
                in: {
                  $toString: "$$this"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }).exec(function(err,result) {
        if(err){
            res.send(err)
        }
        console.log(result)
       // string = "eqfeed_callback('features':["+result+"])";
        res.json(result);
```

and error

```
{"operationTime":"6887428625520394251","ok":0,"code":2,"codeName":"BadValue","$clusterTime":{"clusterTime":"6887428625520394251","signature":{"hash":"0WZkZ4Rt5ldDlszBCucqYlEXedw=","keyId":"6852375211279384577"}},"name":"MongoError"}
```

this is the RAW JSON

```
{"coordinates":[{"$numberDecimal":"115.91138270694381"},{"$numberDecimal":"-31.88770435287793"}],"currentTime":1599186425260}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try,

- `$map` to iterate loop of `coordinates` array and `$toString` to convert type in string

**MongoDB 4.4 or Above**

- Starting in MongoDB 4.4, as part of making [find()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/index.html#projection) projection consistent with aggregation’s `$project` stage

```
location.find({},
{
  "location.coordinates": {
    $map: {
      input: "$location.coordinates",
      in: { $toString: "$$this" }
    }
  }
})
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/djrhIhmLR2J)

---

**Any MongoDB Version**

- Use [aggregate()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) method, and `$addFields` to update location field

```
location.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      "location.coordinates": {
        $map: {
          input: "$location.coordinates",
          in: { $toString: "$$this" }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { $limit: 5000 }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/eJoJ1pjy4U5)

Comment: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

Comment: The error I got {"operationTime":"6887428625520394251","ok":0,"code":2,"codeName":"BadValue","$clusterTime":{"clusterTime":"6887428625520394251","signature":{"hash":"0WZkZ4Rt5ldDlszBCucqYlEXedw=","keyId":"6852375211279384577"}},"name":"MongoError"}

Comment: I am not sure exactly what is the version of your mongodb? because this will support in version 4.4, let me know if your mongodb version is below 4.4 then you have to use aggregate()

Comment: i am using mongoose ("mongoose": "^5.10.10",) and mongodb Atlas (4.2.10).

Comment: it did not work - I am still getting `{"$numberDecimal":"-31.941225025832598"}]`

Comment: Add raw JSON - I think the issue is the proccessing time because on small queries like $limit 500 no issues on larger queries issues